# Owl carousel not working in angular 4 app

Tags: jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I am using owl carousel in my app. But the problem is after adding all the necessary files like owl.carousel.min.css and owl.carousel.min.js its not working and not even showing error. I've checked in debugger and in networks i dont see owl.carousel.min.js. Can anyone guide me here. Where am I wrong. this one I am using is from jquery.

I tried to look up for answers on stackoverflow but none helped me so far.

Comment: Please check all the file path are correct. You can use ctrl+U to check source code of the page and insure that all files are properly added and there code are coming.(by click ing individual link)

Comment: *after adding all the necessary files like* | Adding library files is the first step but not enough, you should initialize owl carousel, did you?

Comment: Are you using `angular-owl-carousel` or downloaded css & js files?

And I believe Owl carousel requires JQuery, so make sure you have JQuery linked too.

as @AlivetoDie mentioned, it very likely a path error.

Can't help you if you don't post your code & file structure.